# URL given by docker is not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, streamlit

I am trying to run my streamlit app via docker. Since I want to run my code in a linux system, I am trying first it it runs in my windows system.

So I ran my container and ran a command which gave me two URLs. But both of the urls are not working.

[This is the terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbUTW.png)

[This the result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPTQp.png)

Do I have to mention any port number? And if yes, then how to find my local system's port?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  Just the text "this is the result" doesn't really explain what's going on.  Details like the application source code, URL, and error message need to be included directly in the question as text, not as images and not behind links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong port number, please try to use `-p 8501:8501` in your docker command and then go to `localhost:8501` in your browser.

Comment: Thank you Brother, your advice worked. Actually I am new to docker and I was trying to open that particular link.

Comment: @NikhilPanchal if worked please mark it as solved. There is a button for that next to the answer. I am glad to help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.


I have tested this out on my other system with Ubuntu, where I can access the app using the internal URL (When run using Docker).


But on my M1 mac, it's working on the localhost:8501 and not the internal URL.

Has some figured out an explanation for this?


`FROM python:3.8
    WORKDIR /app
    RUN pip install streamlit
    EXPOSE 8501
    COPY . /app
    ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "hello"]`

Comment: @programandoconro I had the issue... It opens on localhost:8501 but the Network and the External URL provided doesn't seem to work. Any reason why this happens??

Answer (score 0):

First check if you are able to ping the internal IP of the docker container from the host machine.
then export multiple ports using the following args:-

```
docker run -p <host_port1>:<container_port1> -p <host_port2>:<container_port2>
```